# Laravel File::deleteDirectory returns true, but directory didn’t actually delete

Tags: laravel, file, storage, delete-directory

```php
$cellDirectory = storage_path() . '/app/public/uploads/images/' . $cell->user_id . '/' . $cell->id;
if (is_dir($cellDirectory)) { 
     $success = File::deleteDirectory($cellDirectory); 
}
```

$success is true, but directory and files didn’t actually delete.

Files in directory have chmod 644

Directory chmod 755

also strange, as the folder was created in this way:

```php
if (!is_dir($path)) { 
   File::makeDirectory($path, 0777, true); 
}
```

ask for help, thanks

Answer (score -2):

In Linux you cannot delete a non-empty dir unless you specify the argument "-r" (recursive), perhaps it follows the same logic and you have look up the right way to delete a non-empty dir in laravel.